# Sequelize Tedious strips 0's from decimal

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express, sequelize.js, tedious

Messing around with Sequelize on an MSSQL DB and all was going well until I realized that it was pulling the decimal out of the DB and stripping the 0's off.

Model Snippet:

```
  rate1: {
      type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(10, 2),
      require: true,
  },
```

Data IN database snippet:

```
  10.50
```

Coming out of the DB snippet (in console.log):

```
  rate1: 10.5,
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Side note: Yes I know I can bandaide this with javascript, but doesn't it seem a bit stupid to strip off characters if it's stored that way only to have to go back and put them on again?

Comment: What does it log if you feed it the value 10.00? Unless your logging is using [`.toFixed(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to always produce 2 decimal places it will be truncating trailing 0's.

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with a decimal data type. 10.5 and 10.50 are the same thing. If you are looking to print a string data type with specific precision, use one of the built in JavaScript functions like:

number.**toFixed**(numberOfDecimals);

If you want it to be exactly 10.50 all the time and are not using it as a number value, consider storing it as a string.